# MSWord Richly Formatted Text Paste into Webgui Text Input Field for Database Submission

Tags: .net, visual-studio, silverlight, internet-explorer, ms-word

I have several richly formatted paragraphs in a Word 2003 document. How do I copy each paragraph and paste it in a text input field with all the formatting in place?

The main objective is to make each paragraph as an object in the database so users can add and rearrange these objects(paragraphs) in custom order to generate their custom DOC file.

So far the only way I can think of is to:

```
1) SaveAs this DOC file in XML format
2) Find the WordML for this particular paragraph
3) Select and Copy the specific WordML region
4) Paste it into the web browser text input field
5) Submit and save into the database.
```

My ideal method would be to:

```
1) Open the DOC/DOCX file
2) Select and Copy the paragraph within Word 2003/2007/2010
3) Paste it into the web browser text input field
4) Submit and save into the database.
```

My ideal method skips the part where the user needs to save the DOC file in XML format and manually having to search for the WordML tags and finding the paragraph they need to copy. I'd like the UI to handle of this task but maybe this is just wishful thinking. Is this ideal method doable? If not in Word 2003, would Word 2007/2010 work?